# 404 The requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache

I have a form that collects data and may take several hours to complete since it has an editor where users can add creative elements. If the form is submitted after an hour or so, the site redirects to a 404 Not Found, the URL was not found on this server. I tested this using a very simple form processing script that prints out POST data and still got the error. This seems to only happen on our linux server. I have a WAMP local server running the same script and the POST data sends through fine, no matter how long the form is idle for. Any clues as to what I can try change on the Apache config or PHP side. Thanks

Comment: Naively, it sounds like it's session related, although I don't know why even this would cause a problem (sessions are in PHP). Can you post the html for the `form` as seen by the browser, with the URL in the `action` attribute? You can anonymize the domain on the URL.

Comment: Are you using csrf tokens or such on your form, `several hours to complete`, thats not ideal.